# how to highlight only cell when click on jqgrid grid

Tags: jqgrid

I have jqgrid in which cells are created by java as a hyperlink, attached the image for the same.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYEW4.jpg)

I want to highlight that particulate cell when i click on any count on that jqgrid.
Please refer image for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jqGrid supports cell editing, which can be activated by adding the option `cellEdit: true`. It's important that it allows to edit content of not every columns, but the columns, which have `editable: true` property. If the column don't have `editable: true` property the **the cell will be highlighted**. Thus if you don'u use currently editing feature in the grid and you don't have `editable: true` property in any columns of `colModel` then adding `cellEdit: true` option of jqGrid should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi @Oleg, Thanks for this and it is working, however it is working when u click on anywhere on cell but not in hyperlink. I have hyperlink on cell as a number, you can see attached image. When i  click on hyperlink it calls javascript method, cellEdit: true is not working in this case.

Comment: @SurajBhandari: You are welcome! I don't see any hyperlink on the picture, which you included. Do you use custom formatter to create the limks? Which behavior you expect onClick on the hyperlink? It your code work on click then you can select the cell by call of [editCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing#methods) method. It start editing of the cell or select the cell if the cell isn't editable.

Comment: The number which u see in image actually hyperlink created from server side, when u click on these number it should highlight that cell.